# mapping multiple sets in one table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've got a `User` an a `Log` class (which I cannot change):

```
class User {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Log> accessLogs;
    private Set<Log> actionLogs;
}

class Log {
    private String what;
    private Date when;
}
```

A possible mapping will look like:

```
<class name="com.example.User" table="users">
    <id name="id" access="field">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" length="256" />

    <set name="accessLogs" table="user_access_logs" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="`when`">
        <key column="user_id" />
        <composite-element class="com.example.Log">
            <property name="what" length="512" />
            <property name="when" column="`when`" />
        </composite-element>
    </set>

    <set name="actionLogs" table="user_action_logs" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="`when`">
        <key column="user_id" />
        <composite-element class="com.example.Log">
            <property name="what" length="512" />
            <property name="when" column="`when`" />
        </composite-element>
    </set>

</class>
```

This works fine and maps on the following database tables:

```
users
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | john |
|  2 | bill |
|  3 | nick |
+----+------+

user_access_logs
+---------+------------+---------------------+
| user_id | what       | when                |
+---------+------------+---------------------+
|       1 | logged in  | 2010-09-21 11:25:03 |
|       1 | logged out | 2010-09-21 11:38:24 |
|       1 | logged in  | 2010-09-22 10:19:39 |
|       2 | logged in  | 2010-09-22 11:03:18 |
|       1 | logged out | 2010-09-22 11:48:16 |
|       2 | logged in  | 2010-09-26 12:45:18 |
+---------+------------+---------------------+

user_action_logs
+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| user_id | what          | when                |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+
|       1 | edit profile  | 2010-09-21 11:28:13 |
|       1 | post comment  | 2010-09-21 11:30:40 |
|       1 | edit profile  | 2010-09-21 11:31:17 |
|       1 | submit link   | 2010-09-22 10:21:02 |
|       2 | submit review | 2010-09-22 11:10:22 |
|       2 | submit link   | 2010-09-22 11:11:39 |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+
```

My question is how is it possible in hibernate to map those 2 sets (`accessLogs` and `actionLogs`) into the same table producing the following schema for the logs:

```
user_logs
+---------+---------------+---------------------+--------+
| user_id | what          | when                | type   |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+--------+
|       1 | logged in     | 2010-09-21 11:25:03 | access |
|       1 | edit profile  | 2010-09-21 11:28:13 | action |
|       1 | post comment  | 2010-09-21 11:30:40 | action |
|       1 | edit profile  | 2010-09-21 11:31:17 | action |
|       1 | logged out    | 2010-09-21 11:38:24 | access |
|       1 | logged in     | 2010-09-22 10:19:39 | access |
|       1 | submit link   | 2010-09-22 10:21:02 | action |
|       2 | logged in     | 2010-09-22 11:03:18 | access |
|       2 | submit review | 2010-09-22 11:10:22 | action |
|       2 | submit link   | 2010-09-22 11:11:39 | action |
|       1 | logged out    | 2010-09-22 11:48:16 | access |
|       2 | logged in     | 2010-09-26 12:45:18 | access |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+--------+
```

**Edit**: I want to retain the Java code and Set semantics as is. I'm looking for something like a discriminator, a formula or a hibernate API extension which will solve this without touching the Java code. Maybe something along the lines (imaginary hibernate configuration follows):

```
<set name="accessLogs" table="user_logs" ... formula="type='access'">
    <key column="user_id" />
    <composite-element class="Log">
        ...
    </composite-element>
</set>

<set name="actionLogs" table="user_logs" ... formula="type='action'">
    <key column="user_id" />
    <composite-element class="Log">
        ...
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

**Edit2**: I haven't got a full solution to this yet. I'm sure it can be done, possibly by extending some hibernate API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Maurizio wrote, you need to use the `where` attribute to retrieve only the rows that belong  to each collection.

To ***insert*** rows using the additional column, you need to add the following element inside the `<set>`:

```
<sql-insert>
  insert into user_logs(user_id, what, [when], type)
  values(?, ?, ?, 'access')
</sql-insert>
```

That essentially tells Hibernate to use that specific SQL instead of generating it. Note that I had to manually escape the `when` column.

Bonus: to add the extra column to the DB, use the following (after closing the `<class>`)

```
<database-object>
  <create>alter table user_logs add type char(6)</create>
  <drop></drop>
</database-object>
```

Interesting bit: I wrote and tested this using *NHibernate*, but it was ported directly, so it should work exactly the same.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try to map set in this way:

```
<set name="accessLogs" table="user_logs" where="type='access'">
```

Comment: Thanks, that rocks. Now I only have to find a way to inject "access" into a type column which does not exist in my model.

Comment: +1 This is what I did it in a similar situation, and it's working fine.

Comment: Yes but I cannot distinguish between access and action logs since the user_logs table has only got `user_id`, `what`, `when`.

Comment: I need to do it via hibernate configuration. I cannot modify or extend my model.

Comment: then there is only way in order to do that chaining where condition:
where="what = 'logged in' or what='what else'"

Answer (score 1):

why doesn't it work to just combine the lists into one list?  Both of your lists are of the same class.

EDIT - If you want to preserve having 2 lists, then create a third list that is the combination, and only persist that.  You will have to control access to accessors of the two lists, so you know when to update the third, but shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I'd like to solve this with only changing the hibernate mapping code.

Comment: @cherouvim if you have 2 sets, you need to map the sets.  If you want one set, you have to change your code.

Comment: I need 2 sets and I can map them but I want them mapped to a single table.

Comment: @cherouvim, then try creating a third set, like i suggested in my answer, and map that -- then you have one persistent set, and your domain logic works on the two sets...

Comment: A third set would do the job but I need to know whether this is solvable only by configuration or hibernate extensions.