# NHibernate Linking Table with Data

Tags: sql, nhibernate, many-to-many, metadata

SQL 2008 | .NET 4.0 | NHibernate 3.1 | NHibernate.Castle 3.1 | Castle.Core 2.5.2

So I have a linking table with metadata, like the author of this question [NHibernate Mapping a Many to Many with Data on Join Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197890/)

Initially, I mapped just like the answer to this question as it seemed the most parsimonious way to handle it. However, after turning on `show_sql` and observing what was going on, the ID lookups ended up yielding N+1 queries where N is the number of associations.

Observe this example database that is analogous to my actual data, defined in sql-like syntax

```
CREATE TABLE [User] 
(
  Id int PRIMARY KEY 
)

CREATE TABLE UserPref 
(
  Id int PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(32)
)

CREATE TABLE UserPrefAssociation 
(
  UserId int,
  PrefId int,
  Value varchar(32)
)
```

I hacked the following code together with this User one-to-many object mapping `IList<UserPrefAssociation> Preferences { get; set; }`

```
    public IDictionary<string, string> GeneratePrefDict()
    {
        return Preferences
            .ToDictionary(i => i.UserPref.Name, i => i.Value);
    }
```

Sure, this works great, but as mentioned before, each `i.UserPref.Name`, is an additional query to SQL.

After playing in SQL, I have found the query that accomplishes what I want. My question then becomes how can I do this with NHibernate?

```
SELECT UserPref.Name, UserPrefAssociation.Value
FROM [User] 
    INNER JOIN UserPrefAssociation ON [User].Id = UserPrefAssociation.UserId
    INNER JOIN UserPref ON UserPrefAssociation.UserPrefId = UserPref.Id
WHERE [User].Id = 1
```

~~~~SOLVED~~~~~

```
    using NHibernate.Linq;
    ...
    public IDictionary<string, string> GeneratePrefDict(ISession s)
    {
        return 
            (from entry in s.Query<User_UserPref>()
             where entry.User == this
             select new
             {
                 key = entry.UserPref.Name,
                 value = entry.Value
             })
             .ToDictionary(i => i.key, i => i.value);
    }
```

Generates this SQL

```
NHibernate: select userpref1_.Name as col_0_0_, user_userp0_.Value as col_1_0_ f
rom User_UserPref user_userp0_ left outer join UserPref userpref1_ on user_userp
0_.UserPrefId=userpref1_.Id where user_userp0_.UserId=@p0;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (
0)]
```

Which is better than N+1 queries, and solves my issue.

Comment: Are you wanting to achieve this fetching strategy from a mapping perspective or by using QueryOver or Linq?

Comment: Any would be good. I mainly just want to use NHibernate to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you are wanting with `Futures` and `QueryOver`.  Take a look at the following article:

[Fighting cartesian product (x-join) when using NHibernate 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266180/fighting-cartesian-product-x-join-when-using-nhibernate-3-0-0/5285739#5285739)

If you can't visualize how to accomplish what you need from the above I can tailor that example more to your needs.

Comment: Well, I'm accepting this answer because you tried, and it looks like it would indeed solve the problem with a massive code-mess.